# Checkbox field popup

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a checkbox field, and i want if user checks that field then it should ask are you sure,if press ok then it should continue otherwise not?

Comment: By 'continue', do you mean it should cause a controller action to fire, or you do you mean it should just control whether or not the checkbox gets checked?

Comment: By continue I mean that checkbox which which was checked should remain checked otherwise if user selects no then checkbox should be unchecked

Answer (score 1):

you should call a javascript function on checkbox's onclick event like mentioned below -

```
onclick="if(confirm( 'Are you sure?')){ return true; } else {return false;};"
```

Comment: still not getting the msg after adding that page in the layout

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
      <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!Contact.Apex_Context__c}" 
           onchange="if ( (this.checked) && (!confirm('Are you sure?')) ){this.checked=false}"/>
```

A couple of points to note:

(1) I've assumed you only want the confirmation when the user checks the box, not when they clear it.
(2) I've only tested this in chrome.

Comment: not working
I added this visualforce page in the layout by keeping this in form tag,but when I checked the checkbox,no msg is displayed.

Comment: This worked for me in chrome - what browser are you using?  Also, when you say you added the VF page in the layout - are you expecting this to interact with a checkbox on a standard page?

Comment: I am using chrome, and yes i want it to interact with the standard page
here is the code:
<apex:page standardController="custom object">
<apex:form>
<apex:inputCheckBox value="{!Custom obj.custom field}" 
onchange="if ( (this.checked) && (!confirm('Are you sure?')) ){this.checked=false}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: The visualforce is disconnected from the standard page.  If you check the box on the standard page, that won't have any effect on the visualforce elements.